# How can I change the hover to onclick in css?

Tags: css

I have tried to change the hover to click
and search online already
but it still does not work
how can i change the code to onclick
so i can click and show the drop down menu?

The pattern

```
$* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
padding: 0;
}
ul a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffefc6;
.menu {
max-width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style-type: none;
background-color:#333;
font-weight:bold;
```

The effect

```
$.drop-down {
 position: relative;
 }
 .submenu {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 8;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
 }
 .submenu-item {
 display: block;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: height 0.5s ease;
 }
 .drop-down:hover .submenu {
 opacity: 1;
 }
.drop-down:hover .submenu-item {
overflow: visible;
height: 30px;
}
```

About the html code

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="itembox drop-down">
<a class="item" href="#">Intro</a>
<div class="submenu">
<a class="submenu-item" href="#">Seting　</a>
<a class="submenu-item" href="#">Rule　</a>
<a class="submenu-item" href="#">Mode　</a>
<a class="submenu-item" href="#">Type　</a>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: show you html please

Comment: You want it to work with click or hover (if hover works)?

Comment: where is your html code

Comment: @Abhishek I want it to work with click (now is hover and show the drop down menu)

Comment: but you must add html to your question if you want us to help you(edit question)

Comment: Sorry for that I forget to show html

Comment: There is no “onclick” in CSS. Did you mean that you tried a JavaScript solution? Then _show us_ what you tried. (Please go read [ask] and [mcve], if you have not done so yet.) In CSS there’s stuff like `:active` and `:focus`, but both are not suitable for what you want. `:focus-within` could kinda help with that, but that has no IE/Edge support yet.

Comment: @misorude There is only hover in CSS?

Comment: I didn’t say that, I said there was no “onclick” (or direct, absolute 1:1 equivalent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript, css can't listen to click events.

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var elt = document.getElementById(id);
  elt.style.display = elt.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="toggle('submenu-1')">
    Option 1
    <ul id="submenu-1" class="submenu">
      <li>Sub-option 1.1</li>
      <li>Sub-option 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li onclick="toggle('submenu-2')">
    Option 2
    <ul id="submenu-2" class="submenu">
      <li>Sub-option 2.1</li>
      <li>Sub-option 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I add more option?

Comment: What do you mean by *more option*?

Comment: i want to add two more menu and submenu

Comment: The use different IDs for the sub menus. I edited my snippet, accept my answer if everything is OK for you.